# there is a smallest positive number $p$ for which $f(p)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous with $f(0)=1$. Show that if there is a positive number $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)=0$, then there is a smallest positive number $p$ for which $f(p)=0$.

I think we want to find the infimum of the set $\{x |x>0, f(x)=0\}$ but I am unable to proceed further. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If not, then you can find $x_1< x_0$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$. Similarly, you can find a monotonically decreasing sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$. Can you prove that this sequence has a limit, $p$? What is $f(p)$?  Is $p>0$?

Comment: okay, since the sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by 0, it should have a limit $x$ and $x>0$ but how do i show $f(x)=0$? @Mathmo123

Comment: Every non-empty set of real numbers which has a lower bound has an infimum. the set $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed and bounded from below. Therefore infimum $p$ exists and $f(p)=0$.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya its intersection with $[0,\infty)$ is bounded from below. To OP:, you need continuity to show the infimum is $>0$, and that $f$ evaluated at the infimum is $0$.

Comment: You do need to use the fact that $f$ is continuous! Also be a bit careful: at first, you can only conclude that the limit $x\ge 0$.

Comment: its not equal to zero since f(0)=1 @Mathmo123

Comment: Exactly. So all that remains is to show that $f(x) = 0$. And for that, you need to use continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is absolutely correct. The set $\{x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)=0\}\subset \mathbb R$ is obviously bounded below and therefore (by completeness of $\mathbb R$ has an infimum, say $x_0$.

We now prove $f(x_0)=0$. This follows from the series criterion for continuity. In more detail: Since $x_0$ is the infimum of $\{x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)=0\}$ there exists a series $(x_n)\subset\{x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)=0\} $ with $x_n\to x_0$. By continuity we then have
$$ f(x_0)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim 0 = 0. $$
Further, the construction of $x_0$ as infimum yields $x_0\ge 0$. Since $f(x_0)=1$, $x_0\ne 0$ is obvious and $x_0>0$ follows immediately.